# /usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: line 1: ucgi:: command not found

Tags: macos, ssh, chmod

I followed instructions at http://www.devthought.com/2009/09/19/get-ssh-copy-id-in-mac-os-x/ in order to get ssh-copy-id to work on my mac.
Now I am getting an error when running: `ssh-copy-id`

```
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: line 1: ucgi:: command not found
stat: script:: stat: No such file or directory
stat: No: stat: No such file or directory
stat: such: stat: No such file or directory
stat: file: stat: No such file or directory
stat: or: stat: No such file or directory
stat: directory: stat: No such file or directory
```

I have tried to follow the instructions here: https://github.com/beautifulcode/ssh-copy-id-for-OSX but I every time I run `ssh-copy-id` I get the same error.  How do I fix my situation and get `ssh-copy-id` to work properly?

Comment: The `ucgi:: command not found` error comes from a removed repository at the [referenced URL](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/ucgi/~cjwatson/cvsweb/openssh/contrib/ssh-copy-id?rev=1.8;content-type=text%2Fplain).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use the below command

```
sudo curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/beautifulcode/ssh-copy-id-for-OSX/master/ssh-copy-id.sh -o /usr/local/bin/ssh-copy-id
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/ssh-copy-id
```

Answer (score 16):

IMHO, the simplest way, as you are on a mac, is to use brew.

```
brew install ssh-copy-id
```

Comment: Good answer, though sometimes this is less preferable because new Macs don't come installed with Brew when you are setting up your SSH login.

Answer (score 2):

The repository referenced in the first link is broken.

Try installing it this way:

```
sudo curl https://raw.github.com/beautifulcode/ssh-copy-id-for-OSX/master/ssh-copy-id.sh -o /usr/local/bin/ssh-copy-id
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/ssh-copy-id
```

Comment: I did those two steps, and I get the same error when I run: `ssh-copy-id`

Comment: This shouldn't end up in the same error (as the GitHub code is available and doesn't output these lines!). You should ensure that the old files are cleared up before or overwritten.

Comment: Thanks. I think I was not being accurate with the last line.